# Is there any way to define Hibernate custom type in DTO

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My Entity class looks like below:

```
@TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class)
public class Field extends BaseEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "title", length = 50)
  private String title;

  @Column(name = "acreage", precision = 10, scale = 2)
  private BigDecimal acreage;

  @Column(name = "gps_coordinates")
  private Point gpsCoordinates;

  @Column(name="zip_code", length = 10)
  private String zipCode;

  @Type(type = "string-array")
  @Column(name = "photo_path", columnDefinition = "text[]")
  private String[] photoPath;
}
```

and Want to have DTO class like below:

```
public interface FieldDetails {

    String getTitle();
    Point gpsCoordinates();
    BigDecimal getAcreage();
    
    String getMemo1();
    String[] getPhotoPath();

}
```

And using the below JPA method to get FieldDetails:

```
@Query(value = """
            select f.title, 
            f.gps_coordinates as gpsCoordinates,
            f.acreage,
            f.memo1,
            f.photo_path as photoPath
            from public.field f where f.id = :id
            """, nativeQuery = true)
    Object getFieldDetails(Long id);
```

When using this method I am getting below error:

**No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003**

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the interface `FieldDetails`, all the methods must be getter methods.

Update `Point gpsCoordinates();` to `Point getGpsCoordinates();`

Add the appropriate alias for the fields selected.

```
@Query(value = """
        select f.title as title, 
        f.gpsCoordinates as gpsCoordinates,
        f.acreage as acreage,
        f.memo1 as memo1,
        f.photoPath as photoPath
        from public.field f where f.id = :id
        """)
FieldDetails getFieldDetails(Long id);
```

`memo1` also does not seem to exist on the entity.

For the dialect issue, it looks the type `StringArrayType` is not registered as part of the default dialect in use.

Depending on you database provider, extend the appropriate dialect and register the type `2003` to map it to `StringArrayType.class`.

An example for extending a Postgres Dialect

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType;
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect;

public class PostgreSQL9CustomDialect extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {

    public PostgreSQL9CustomDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerHibernateType(2003, StringArrayType.class.getName());
    }

}
```